# Facebook Android SDK ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class) always returns true

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am using ShareDialog to share the link on Facebook wall. Irrespective of whether the Facebook native app is installed or not on the device, `ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)` is always returning true. 
 Is this the expected behavior or I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

It returns true because there will always be a dialog that can share links.

If the native app is installed, it will switch to the native app. If the native app is not there, it will open up a web dialog instead.

There are some content types (like photos) where you cannot fallback to a web dialog, and in those cases, the canShow will return false.